# HELP Decrypting Lua files

Tags: ida, android, decryption, game-hacking, lua

i'm trying to mod a game named : DDTank Mobile, which is on both Android & IOS.
This game runs on cocos2d engine, the thing is the lua files are encrypted.
I read somewhere to look for 'sign' at the beginning of each lua files, but this is what i find

### [image: MEGameStartup.lua]

[image]

The sign seems to be `��+` in utf-8.
In hex it is : `F8 8B 2B`

I found that you can use IDA to look into the Binaries of the SO File and Find the encryption key in a function called ApplicationDidFinishLaunching, so I tried not knowing what to do.
Here's the pseudo-code from IDA: https://pastebin.com/T0RxB6ML

In this function, there is a call to `StartConfig::enter` and inside it there is this function used `XXTeaEncrypt::setXXTeaKeyAndSign`, here's the pseudo-code from IDA:
https://pastebin.com/SjdvsKya

Link to the APK : https://m.apkpure.com/ddtank-mobile/com.wan.ddten/
Some Lua files + lib (SO) files : https://mega.nz/file/LJ0EXKiQ#aRLpaed4LXV0fSg9AK9-5-kZYYvOoHo49ytbDV6dMuI

Comment: I tried looking at all .lua files, however i may have done it wrong but i couldn't find any useful comments that would link me up to original file version. I also tried getting the oldest version of the game available on apkpure, to see changes, unfortunately they are obfuscated+encrypted.
As for for the link you've sent, it might be useful in the future but sadly i cant find the xxxtea decryption key.
Im new to this domain

Comment: my bad for using wrong words

Answer (score 1):

Update on this :

I managed to get through the obfuscated lua files by hooking the luaL_loadbuffer exported function from libengine.so using frida, and managed to dump the game code.

After that i built a lua wrapper around the game, which would execute my lua code. Short after this, I realized that this game has plenty of stuff server side, so I couldnt do anything 'edgy' like changing my fightpower, diamonds, tickets, even if I was to send some hacky net message, server would check, i mean fair enough.

I tried bypassing the payment request, that i saw while looking through lua files (PayCallBackModelEntity.lua)

Anyways, I think i'm dropping this, can't do much, was a great opportunity for me to learn though :)